# Missing values in Confusion matrix in Decision Tree in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree

I have a problem in building confusion matrix using Decision tree method. The data set is extremely imbalanced and the population of third label ("C") is about 1%.

I have no idea why prediction results of C is all zero(0).

```
# load the package
install.packages('rpart')
library(rpart)
library(caret)
# load data
data<-read.csv("Drisk0122_01.csv", header=TRUE)
data<-data[ , c(3:43)]
data$Class<-factor(data$Class, levels = c(1,2, 3), labels=c("A", "B", "C"))

set.seed(42)
training.samples <- createDataPartition(y=data$Class, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
training.samples

train  <- data[training.samples, ]
test <- data[-training.samples, ]

############tree
install.packages("tree")
library(tree)
treemod<-tree(Class~. , data=train)
plot(treemod)
text(treemod)

cv.trees<-cv.tree(treemod, FUN=prune.misclass ) # for classification decision tree
plot(cv.trees)

prune.trees <- prune.misclass(treemod, best=4)  # for regression decision tree, use prune.tree function
plot(prune.trees)
text(prune.trees, pretty=0)


library(e1071)
treepred <- predict(prune.trees, test, type='class')
confusionMatrix(treepred, test$Class)
```

**The results are as follows:**

> confusionMatrix(treepred, test$Class)
>   Confusion Matrix and Statistics

```
      Reference
```

Prediction    A    B    C
         A 2324  360   28
         B  211  427    3
         C    0    0    0

Overall Statistics

```
           Accuracy : 0.8205         
             95% CI : (0.807, 0.8333)
No Information Rate : 0.756          
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16      

              Kappa : 0.4775
```

Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 4.526e-15

Statistics by Class:

```
                 Class: A Class: B Class: C
```

Sensitivity            0.9168   0.5426 0.000000
Specificity            0.5257   0.9166 1.000000
Pos Pred Value         0.8569   0.6661      NaN
Neg Pred Value         0.6708   0.8673 0.990755
Prevalence             0.7560   0.2347 0.009245
Detection Rate         0.6931   0.1273 0.000000
Detection Prevalence   0.8088   0.1912 0.000000
Balanced Accuracy      0.7212   0.7296 0.500000

**[Please find the image of the results from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsZGl.png)**

Comment: `C` is very rare, and the way you've configured your model it thinks it does best by never predicting `C`. There are a lot of approaches to imbalanced data, from making sure your training sample includes enough C, oversampling C cases, using different hyperparameters or a different loss function/metric to optimize... I don't think the question belongs on Stack Overflow, but there are **lots** of resources about imbalanced data, you should do some reading and try some stuff before posting on stats.stackexchange

Comment: That said, even then your C cases may be difficult to distinguish from A and B, in which case *it might make sense to never predict C*...